# why the tensorflow classifer accuracy is less on mobile as compare to laptop

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I have retrained the custom tensorflow model using the 2 googleCodelabs whose links are given below.

Tensorflow for poet 1: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0
Tensorflow for poet 2 :
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#0

After the retraining I get the `retrained_model.pb` file
And after the retraining when I want to classify for the unseen data on my laptop I get the top 5 result.

But when I load the same `retrainde_model.pb` model inside my android app and perform the prediction on the same image it gives me the different 5 result.

I am confused why it is happening. Why is the mobile application not returning the same result?

Is the mobile application have the less resources due to which the mobile application is giving the bad result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the android model in Android application then before loading into android mobile you will have to quanitze the graph. Therefore due to the quantization the accuracy on mobile cause is little bit different than the accuracy on laptop.