# Tensorflow Retrained Model Behaves Differently on Android Device

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I have retrained the model with some custom images as explained in the tensorflow for poets tutorial.

When I run the model on my computer with the below command 
`python -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=tf_files/test_photos/apple.jpg`

I am expecting it to classify as an apple and I get the correct classification result which is:

> apple 1.0 orange 1.40016e-08 lemon 2.19029e-09

When I copy the retrained model and the label file to android studio's assets folder and build the apk, I get different classification results even though I am providing the same image to the model.

[See the image of the classification result from the app that is built using the same model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Lml.jpg)

I thought the problem was caused by the different tensorflow versions of anaconda and android studio. Therefore, I upgraded the tensorflow version to 1.7.0 to build the model and in android studio tensorflow's dependencies are

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
```

I also tried the dependency

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.7.0'
```

But I received another error and app crashed immediately after launching so I had to turn back to

```
'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705475/why-the-tensorflow-classifer-accuracy-is-less-on-mobile-as-compare-to-laptop/49820380#49820380

Comment: try this link..

Comment: As Muhammad said it could be because of the quantization of the graph. If the model has overfit you will get very different results. But I think in your case the error might be related to the preprocessing of the image. Bear in mind that the library to preprocess the image in Android and you computer is different. Try an image that doesn't need any preprocessing (as scaling or cropping) in both models.

Comment: I quantized as explained in the tensorflow for poets 2 tutorial and still having the wrong classification results. When I use the quantized model in my computer I get the result: apple 0.999999 orange 8.11136e-07. When I use the same quantized model in android I get:
orange 1.0. It supposed to classify as an apple. @jorgemf By saying try an image that doesn't require any preprocessing, do you mean for training or testing? In test, I do not need to do any cropping because the camera is already focused on the object and there is no background object. Inference image: https://imgur.com/a/wZxY7yj

Comment: @teteckr I mean use exactly the same image in both models, otherwise your results are irrelevant. It might be something in the camera, it might be the cropping or the resizing or whatever. Test with exactly the same image in both models. I had models that due to several reason a small amount of white noise in an image changed the results completely, but it doesn't mean the model predicts something different but the model is wrong and you have to re-train it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, even though the optimization and quantization was done, I couldn't make it work with tensorflow for mobile. Same image on mobile and on computer outputed completely different results.

Therefore, I changed to Tensorflow Lite. With tensorflow lite my problem is solved. One short note: Tensorflow lite is not supported on windows (especially toco), therefore I had to use ubuntu.